# Machine learning on Percent as dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, continuous-data

I am working on a problem where I am tasked to predict users into 'High users' and 'Low users'. Dependent variable provided is in percent of orders (%) which is calculated as (#orders placed/#sales visit).
I want to model user characteristics to "% of orders" to be able predict which users should be targeted.
I converted continuous variable to categorical after looking at distribution and below categories shows decent equal distribution in all 3 classes.

- "High" >=70%
- "Medium" 40-70%
- "Low" <= 40%

Questions:

1. Can I remove Medium category to make 'High and Low" extremes as my aim is to predict weather user falls in High or Low category
2. There might be users with less sales visits but high % of orders and vice versa. For Example,

----# Sales Visits-#orders-% orders-Target---
--user A--100-80-80-High---
--user B--1000-800-80-High---
is bucketing both above cases as "High" makes sense?

3. Considering I have good sample population, Can I restrict my analysis on upper 2 quartiles on "#of visits" to overcome concern mentioned in #2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would look at this as binomial data (y out of N - this helps with more appropriate treating cases such as 1/1 vs. 100/100, which are both 100%), as long as you have the numerator and denominator available. By doing that, you also do not need to consider any other way of dealing with that. E.g. if you want to use this model in practice, then restricting yourself to the upper 2 quartiles on "#of visits" is a bit pointless. That would essentially create a model that is only usable for half the population. Additionally, I would guess that in practice one would know the past outcomes, in that case, prediction is the most useful for those with little data, so far, which would be exactly those you would not look at. This might not be that much of an issue, if the process through which visits occur is completely random. If not (in most application I would suspect this), you probably introduce some sampling bias, if you restrict yourself.

I cannot see any reason for why you would remove the medium category. Firstly, it exists in practice, so you need to know what you do about them. Secondly, 69% vs. 71% is not really all that different in practice and drawing an arbitrarily line there is probably not a good idea.